# How to make a JTable entries from outside data?

Tags: java, jtable

I'm looking for a way to make data entries for a table from data collected from a SQL database. I have the code made for grabbing the data from the database but I need help with turning that data into table entries

Comment: Please post the code you have

Answer (score 0):

First create an object to represent each row in the table.

```
public class MyData {
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    
    //add getters/setters
}
```

Then you should create a table model

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
   List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addRow(MyData data) {
      list.add(data);
      fireTableRowsInserted(list.size()-1, list.size()-1);
   }

   //then fill in the required method
   public String getColumnName(int col) {
      switch (col) {
          case 0:
            return "Name";
          case 1:
            return "Description";
      }
      return "";
   }

   public int getRowCount() {
       return list.size();
   }

   public int getColumnCount() {
       return 2; //or however many columns you need
   }

   public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
       MyData data = list.get(row);
       if (col == 0) {
          return data.getName();
       } else if (col == 1) {
          return data.getDesc();
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

Then use that model in your table;

```
MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

Then you you can read data from the database you just have to call

```
tableModel.add(data);
```